# Bypassing the lock screen PIN on Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 without factory reset

Tags: samsung, lock-screens, password, locked-out

My aunt suddenly passed away with no will as she was young. She has a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 that I'm trying to access for pictures off of it for her memorial service.

I've tried at least 20 different 4-digit pins and now it says "Please wait 40 seconds to try again". And I don't want to be completely locked out of it. And I'm trying to avoid factory reset because we want the pictures she took on it. She was a private person so there are no notes about it. And no one knows her email, password, Google accounts, etc.

Is there a way to bypass the pin in a hack-like way that's not illegal?

Comment: yes it's possible to bypass. most likely it's old Android 4 device with no encryption or bootloader lock. but mention device model code first.

Comment: If you are the heir (for a legal perspective) you can contact the online services like Google to give you access to the account of your aunt. On this process you need to prove that you are the heir of your aunt.